# Tabela em Python com DataFrame de tamanhos diferentes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tabela-html

Estou escrevendo um código para registrar pedidos de regra de firewall onde após a entrada dos dados de "Origem", "Destino" e "Porta" quero apresentar as entradas em uma tabela. Estou usando o Pandas para criar a tabela, mas como uma coluna não tem relação com a outra estou com dificuldades em formatar a tabela corretamente. Segue o código de teste:

```
import pandas as pd

src = ['src1', 'src2', 'src3']
dst = ['dst1', 'dst2']
srv = ['srv1']

df_src = pd.DataFrame(src, columns=['Origem'])
df_dst = pd.DataFrame(dst, columns=['Destino'])
df_srv = pd.DataFrame(srv, columns=['Serviço'])

rule = pd.concat([df_src, df_dst, df_srv])
rule.update(rule.fillna(''))

print(rule)
```

A saída do print está com a seguinte formatação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já que as colunas não tem relação uma com a outra eu esperava uma tabela com o seguinte formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe posso fazer isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!!

O seu problema poderia ser resolvido somente adicionando o seguinte argumento na função *rule*, ficando com a seguinte sintaxe:   **rule = pd.concat([df_src, df_dst, df_srv], axis=1)**

- O argumento axis=1 determina que as matrizes devem ser concatenadas no eixo horizontal.

Logo, o código pode ser reescrito como:

```
import pandas as pd

src = ['src1', 'src2', 'src3']
dst = ['dst1', 'dst2']
srv = ['srv1']

df_src = pd.DataFrame(src, columns=['Origem'])
df_dst = pd.DataFrame(dst, columns=['Destino'])
df_srv = pd.DataFrame(srv, columns=['Serviço'])

rule = pd.concat([df_src, df_dst, df_srv], axis=1)
rule.update(rule.fillna(''))

print(rule)
```

**O resultado:**

```
    Origem Destino Serviço
0   src1    dst1    srv1
1   src2    dst2        
2   src3
```

Uma boa explicação sobre axis no pandas está disposto neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean

Espero ter ajudado! 0/

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

O método `pd.concat` irá sempre concatenar os DataFrames um abaixo do outro (afinal, este é o significado de "concatenar"). No lugar disso, recomendo tentar criar o DataFrame final diretamente com:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Origem': src,
    'Destino': dst,
    'Serviço': srv,
})
```

Mas como as listas `src`, `dst` e `srv` não possuem o mesmo tamanho, temos que completá-las com strings vazios até todas terem o mesmo tamanho. Para isso, podemos usar [esta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438818/11161432), chegando no código abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd

src = ['src1', 'src2', 'src3']
dst = ['dst1', 'dst2']
srv = ['srv1']

N = max(len(src), len(dst), len(srv))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Origem': src + [''] * (N - len(src)),
    'Destino': dst + [''] * (N - len(dst)),
    'Serviço': srv + [''] * (N - len(srv)),
})

print(df)
```

output:

```
  Origem Destino Serviço
0   src1    dst1    srv1
1   src2    dst2        
2   src3
```